# Getting all the temporary Internet files after clear history

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Google chrome as a browser. I have made Google chrome as my default browser.

Suppose I have cleared my browsing history in Google chrome and still I want to get all those files that I have visited on the Internet, so is it possible to get all the files after clearing the history clear?

Comment: i have no insight into chrome code, but that would be serious bug, if you could recreate the history after you cleared it...

Comment: Serious bug? Chrome ran as ***root*** when I started it as a regular user with no sudo rights!

Answer (score 1):

You need [undelete software](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) to do this but if you touched your browser and it created new files you can probably forget about it. You need to restore the hidden directory chrome from your home directory: `/home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/`  (if needed make a backup of what is there at the moment)